# Creating Snackbar Using GetX Library

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

I try to use getX to make a snackbar, but it doesn't work.

```
import 'package:get/get.dart';

onPressed: () {
  Get.snackbar(
    "GeeksforGeeks",
    "Hello everyone",
    icon: Icon(Icons.person, color: Colors.white),
    snackPosition: SnackPosition.TOP,
  );
},
```

This is my first expirience with this package.

Comment: Are using GetMaterialApp ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use GetMaterialApp instead of MaterialApp.